# cobalt not display video information after Aug 30

Tags: cobalt

as cobalt spec, we append "env_isVideoInfoVisible=1" to URL like below, it can display video information.
https://www.youtube.com/tv?env_isVideoInfoVisible=1

before Aug 30, it work properly.
but it not work now.
did cobalt or Youtube change any thing or we have to correct our setting?
did YouTube Certification need it also?

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this internally from the player. The patch will go live in a few days.

Comment: Fyi, this is a server-side change. No need to update Cobalt.